# How to create custom Document Libraries and Folders with SharePoint API

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-api

I've got an external application which performs web service calls to SharePoint API. I need to create two functionalities:

1. Create Document Libraries with e.g. foo, bar and baz as required data (columns). The data should be passed via the web service without any manual work from the user.
2. Create Folders inside said Document Libraries with foo and bar as required columns which are automatically populated. Also the order of the columns should be set in the web service call.

I've got a working solution which generates a Document Library with only foo and bar but not baz. How can I add an additional custom column for the baz and populate its value via the web service call. And the same question for the Folder structure. I cannot find a reasonable solution to create dynamically custom columns and place data in them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create a new doc library with foo, bar and baz, copy all the content, then rename the old one to "OBSOLETE" and then rename the new one to the original name.